# Resuable UIPickerView with delegate method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, nib

I want to have a reusable `UIPickerView` which is populated with the JSON object coming from internet. Problem is how to use picker and get values from this picker in different controllers? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: so as I got the idea of the question is: how to do this. But to answer this question you have to post more information, where exactly you have a problem and how it will work

Comment: Fir show your pickerView class.

Comment: I think you want to make one global picker , which can be used in all controller? right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Generalize all picker with single class there is good library for this.

You can use [ActionSheetPicker](https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0) for your requirement.

This is very best maintain library for Picker.

**Example Code for Objective-C:**

```
// Inside a IBAction method:

// Create an array of strings you want to show in the picker:
NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Red", @"Green", @"Blue", @"Orange", nil];

[ActionSheetStringPicker showPickerWithTitle:@"Select a Color"
                                        rows:colors
                            initialSelection:0
                                   doneBlock:^(ActionSheetStringPicker *picker, NSInteger selectedIndex, id selectedValue) {
                                      NSLog(@"Picker: %@, Index: %@, value: %@", 
                                      picker, selectedIndex, selectedValue);
                                    }
                                 cancelBlock:^(ActionSheetStringPicker *picker) {
                                      NSLog(@"Block Picker Canceled");
                                    }
                                      origin:sender];
// You can also use self.view if you don't have a sender
```

Hope this will helps to show picker data in whole project.